# Ionic - when should ionicModal.remove() be called? [Ionic Modal Hide Callback]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my controller, modal views are initialized with a factory by listening to the `$ionicView.afterEnter` event. As the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/) suggests, modal views should be removed whenever the current active ionic view is about to be destroyed. A function is called in the `$ionicView.beforeLeave` callback in order to remove the modal views.

```
.controller('UserProfileCtrl', function($scope, $state, user, ModalFactory) {
    $scope.user = user;

    $scope.checkOrders = function() {
        $state.go('app.orders');
    };

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
        $scope.modals = ModalFactory.getUserProfileModals($scope, user.photos);
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function() {
        $scope.modals.remove();
    });
});

.factory('ModalFactory', function($ionicModal, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    var modalFactory = {};

    modalFactory.getUserProfileModals = function(scope, images) {
        var modals = {
            'views': [],
            'data': []
        };

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/common/image-view.html', { 'scope': scope }).then(function(modal) { modals.views.imageView = modal; });

        if (images) {
            modals.data.images = images;
        }

        modals.open = function(view, slide) {
            Object.keys(this.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
                console.log(key);
            });

            if (view && this.views.hasOwnProperty(view)) {
                this.views[view].show();

                if (view == 'imageView' && slide) {
                    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('image-view').slide(slide);
                }
            }
        };

        modals.close = function(view) {
            Object.keys(this.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
                console.log(key);
            });

            if (view && this.views.hasOwnProperty(view)) {
                this.views[view].hide();
            } else {
                Object.keys(this.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
                    this.views[key].hide();
                });
            }
        };

        modals.remove = function() {
            console.log('remove');
            Object.keys(this.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
                console.log(key);
            });

            this.data.splice(0, this.data.length);

            Object.keys(this.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
                this.views[key].remove();
            });

            this.views.splice(0, this.views.length);
        };

        return modals;
    };

    return modalFactory;
});
```

However, I get the following output in the console when I execute these actions in sequence:

1. call `$scope.modals.open('imageView', 1)`,
2. call `$scope.modals.close()`,
3. navigate to another page with `$state.go('app.orders')`.

[image: Screenshot showing console output]

I tried listening to `$destroy` instead of `$ionicView.beforeLeave`, but then `$scope.modals.remove()` is not called at all. It seems `$destroy` is not fired when I am testing my application with Chrome.

Can anyone tell me when should I remove the modal views, and why is there such an error message in my scenario?

---

### Update

After I modified the code in `ModalFactory` as follows, the error is gone.

```
function open(view, slide) {
    if (view && modals.views.hasOwnProperty(view)) {
        modals.views[view].show();

        if (view == 'imageView' && slide) {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('image-view').slide(slide);
        }
    }
};

function close(view) {
    if (view && modals.views.hasOwnProperty(view)) {
        modals.views[view].hide();
    } else {
        Object.keys(modals.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
            modals.views[key].hide();
        });
    }
};

function remove() {
    console.log('remove');

    modals.data.splice(0, modals.data.length);

    Object.keys(modals.views).forEach(function(key, index) {
        modals.views[key].remove();
    });

    modals.views.splice(0, modals.views.length);
};

modals.open = open;
modals.close = close;
modals.remove = remove;

return modals;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using  $scope.$on('$destroy', ..) method Angular will broadcast a $destroy event just before tearing down a scope and removing the scope from its parent.

Here is the example of how i resolved modal.remove() issue,

```
.factory('ModalFactory', function($ionicModal, $rootScope) {
    var init = function(tpl, $scope) {
        var promise;
        $scope = $scope || $rootScope.$new();

        promise = $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(tpl, {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-right'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            return modal;
        });

        $scope.openModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.show();
        };
        $scope.closeModal = function() {
            $scope.modal.hide();
        };
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $scope.modal.remove();
        });

        return promise;
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }

})
```

And from the controller, pass the current scope of controller and modal template

```
.controller('UserProfileCtrl', function($scope, $state, user, ModalFactory) {    
    ModalFactory.init('image-view.html', $scope)
            .then(function(modal) {
                confirmationModal = modal;
                confirmationModal.show();
            });
})
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: It seems `$destroy` is not always fired when I navigate from one page to another. But once it is fired and the event handler is executed, I receive the same error message as shown in my post. Do you have any idea on why `this.views['imageView']` is undefined in my code?

Comment: It turns out to be a javascript problem which generates the error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for a solution in 2016, it is mentioned that

> $scope.$on('destroy') isn't called in new ionic builds where cache is
>   used

so I came up with a solution to add event listener for animation/transition end on modal.hidden.

First of all this **[solution](http://osvaldas.info/detecting-css-animation-transition-end-with-javascript)** solves the animation end event problem.

The awesome guy made two libraries, one with jQuery Depency, and the other is written in plain javascript.

**jQuery Plugin:**

```
/*
    By Osvaldas Valutis, www.osvaldas.info
    Available for use under the MIT License
*/

;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    var s = document.body || document.documentElement, s = s.style, prefixAnimation = '', prefixTransition = '';

    if( s.WebkitAnimation == '' )   prefixAnimation  = '-webkit-';
    if( s.MozAnimation == '' )      prefixAnimation  = '-moz-';
    if( s.OAnimation == '' )        prefixAnimation  = '-o-';

    if( s.WebkitTransition == '' )  prefixTransition = '-webkit-';
    if( s.MozTransition == '' )     prefixTransition = '-moz-';
    if( s.OTransition == '' )       prefixTransition = '-o-';

    $.fn.extend(
    {
        onCSSAnimationEnd: function( callback )
        {
            var $this = $( this ).eq( 0 );
            $this.one( 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', callback );
            if( ( prefixAnimation == '' && !( 'animation' in s ) ) || $this.css( prefixAnimation + 'animation-duration' ) == '0s' ) callback();
            return this;
        },
        onCSSTransitionEnd: function( callback )
        {
            var $this = $( this ).eq( 0 );
            $this.one( 'webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend transitionend', callback );
            if( ( prefixTransition == '' && !( 'transition' in s ) ) || $this.css( prefixTransition + 'transition-duration' ) == '0s' ) callback();
            return this;
        }
    });
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

or use
**Plain Javascript Library:**

```
/*
    By Osvaldas Valutis, www.osvaldas.info
    Available for use under the MIT License
*/

;( function ( document, window, index )
{
    var s = document.body || document.documentElement, s = s.style, prefixAnimation = '', prefixTransition = '';

    if( s.WebkitAnimation == '' )   prefixAnimation  = '-webkit-';
    if( s.MozAnimation == '' )      prefixAnimation  = '-moz-';
    if( s.OAnimation == '' )        prefixAnimation  = '-o-';

    if( s.WebkitTransition == '' )  prefixTransition = '-webkit-';
    if( s.MozTransition == '' )     prefixTransition = '-moz-';
    if( s.OTransition == '' )       prefixTransition = '-o-';

    Object.prototype.onCSSAnimationEnd = function( callback )
    {
        var runOnce = function( e ){ callback(); e.target.removeEventListener( e.type, runOnce ); };
        this.addEventListener( 'webkitAnimationEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'mozAnimationEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'oAnimationEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'oanimationend', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'animationend', runOnce );
        if( ( prefixAnimation == '' && !( 'animation' in s ) ) || getComputedStyle( this )[ prefixAnimation + 'animation-duration' ] == '0s' ) callback();
        return this;
    };

    Object.prototype.onCSSTransitionEnd = function( callback )
    {
        var runOnce = function( e ){ callback(); e.target.removeEventListener( e.type, runOnce ); };
        this.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'mozTransitionEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'oTransitionEnd', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'transitionend', runOnce );
        this.addEventListener( 'transitionend', runOnce );
        if( ( prefixTransition == '' && !( 'transition' in s ) ) || getComputedStyle( this )[ prefixTransition + 'transition-duration' ] == '0s' ) callback();
        return this;
    };
}( document, window, 0 ));
```

**Next in your Ionic Code, listen to Modal Hide Event:**

```
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
       $( '.modal' ).onCSSAnimationEnd( function()//this example uses jQuery Plugin
       {
           $scope.modal.remove();
       });
      });
```

**Or Plain Javascripy Example:**

```
var item = document.querySelector( '.modal' );   
item.onCSSAnimationEnd( function()
{
    $scope.modal.remove();
});
```

Hope it helps someone someday.